# Getting specific record using user input in form with MongoDB, NodeJS and Angular5

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, angular5

I am trying to get back a record out of my MongoDB database using user input on an Angular template. Here's what's in my api.js file:

```
// Response handling
let response = {
status: 200,
key: [],
message: null
};

router.get('/keys/:key', (req, res, next) => {
connection((db) =>  {    
db.collection('keys')
  .findOne({key: req.params.key})
  .then((keys) => {
      response.key = keys;
      res.json(keys);
    })
  .catch(err => {
      return next({ status: 500, message: 'messed up'})
    });
  });
});
```

Here's my keys.service.ts file:

```
@Injectable()
export class KeysService {

 result: any

 constructor(private _http: Http) {}

 getKeys(typeKey) {

   return this._http.get(`/api/keys/:key${typeKey}`)
     .map(result => this.result = result.json().key);
```

}

}

Here's the template (I apologize about the formatting):

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
 </h1>   
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="typeKey">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getKeyClass(typeKey)">Check Your 
Key Spelling</button>
  <br><br>
  <h2>The Correct Key Spelling is: {{ keySpelling }}</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

What I am receiving as an error right now is "type error, can not read property key of null". It is referring to "key" in the keys.service.ts file on the last line.

I am not using mongoose or monk here. I had this working with a general query of my db that gave me the entire contents of the collection "keys" but when I try and make an individual query, no dice. Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: .then((keys) => {
      response.key = keys;
      res.json(keys);
    })

response here is probably undefined. `keys` is the actual response that is coming back from the API.  try removing `response.key = keys` Theres a good chance `keys` is going to have a `data` property, and that could be what your looking for.  try adding a `console.log(keys)` to see specifically what is being sent back.

Comment: It's your res.json in the node.js portion. Your return object doesn't have a key "key" since you're service is parsing the json and using "key"

Comment: `response` is not defined anywhere, hence it's treated as `null`

Comment: @NeilLunn --Response is actually defined, I forgot to add that. I fixed it.

Comment: Then `keys` is `null`. `findOne()` returns **one** and NOT an "array" anyway. If you are getting `null` in response then the query is incorrect. Check the value of `req.parms.key` because it's a "string" and if you are trying to match to an `ObjectId` or similar other type then the query will return nothing.

Comment: @NeilLunn I am trying to match a string, so that's not the issue. I agree that the query is incorrect, just how is the question.

Comment: @AJGenung Hi AJ-- I forgot to add in there that "keys" replaces the "data" property. I am updating the code now to reflect that.

Comment: `.then((keys) ... ` what is being returned from the API is getting put into that keys property.  colsole.log(keys) and you will probably find that the actual data you are looking for is on a data property on that keys object. at the very minimum you will want to make `response.key = keys.data`

Comment: wait, hold up... what is the point in you creating that response object when your not actually using it?? get rid of that response declaration then do `.this(keys => res.json(keys))`.  the client would then receive a response from the server with all the information already attached to it.  and the `keys` you are sending back would be accessed with `response.data` on the client side. @BILLWAGNER

Comment: @AJGenung I did the console.log(keys) and the sucker is null! So, {key: req.params.key} is not getting the data it looks like. Mystifying.

Comment: do you have the model set up using mongoose?  Is there a `key` property on each document in the database?

Comment: @AJGenung I am not using Mongoose, I am just using MongoDB in Node for this. Maybe I need to use Mongoose or Monk for this. I had this working for querying and returning the whole collection, but when I tried to use template input to bring back one specific result, that's where it fails. In answer to your question, there is a key property for each doc in the db.

Comment: Every time I have used Mongo I always use mongoose to set up my models as well as connecting to the database.  the syntax for connecting they way you are is foreign to me but it seems like you might not be connecting properly.

Comment: @AJGenung Thanks AJ for helping out nonetheless. :)

Comment: Sry I couldn’t be of more help.  But definitely look further into connecting to that database and collection.  Something doesn’t look right there.